# Discord bot to send text messages with image from built in command (Python; Can redo in another language)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I've been working on trying to build a discord bot for a server that you could for example do "!publish [text + upload]" this would then send whatever you've typed (plus the uploaded image) from the bot in the current channel. I had had sqiggly code I was doing in Python off a new tutorials but so far nothing has stuck.

What I've got below is an attempt at having it send an image from the bot on command as a start however it hasn't even functioned this far. If anyone would be able to help me fix this up to get the desired result that would be great, I'm happy to switch up languages if that's easier. So far I've got it repeating text from command (See: $hello the bot will send hello! back. I'll be keeping that command for further use but haven't been able to get anything with an image extension). Have tried both file images and url; tried all the options on discord documentation without success.

```
import discord
import os
from replit import db
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import bot
import asyncio
import datetime as dt

client = discord.Client()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Connected!')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print('Hello world {0.user}'
  .format(client))
  
@client.event 
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author == client.user:
    return

  if message.content.startswith('$hello'):
    await message.channel.send('hello!')


@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def test(ctx):
    await ctx.send('Working!', file=discord.File('image.png'))


client.run(os.environ['TOKEN'])
```

First tutorial I followed had me using replit to code this, store data and keep it cloud-base operational even when the computer wasn't active. The bot is functioning at this time just using the $hello command and anything similar. Nothing with images.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should only use either `client` or `Bot` not both, bot is the better option since it has commands and events. here is your code organized using `commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')`

```py
import discord
import os
from replit import db
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio
import datetime as dt

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Connected! {bot.user}')
  
@bot.event 
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == bot.user:
        return

    #code here

# !hello
@bot.command()
async def hello(ctx):
    await ctx.send('Hey!')

# !test
@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
    await ctx.send('Working!', file=discord.File('image.png'))


bot.run(os.environ['TOKEN'])
```

You have defined two instances and only ran `client`. That is why `!test` did not work

Comment: Thank you for that, code looks much cleaner haha. Unfortunately I haven't been able to get it to work? none of the commands return regardless of how I've shifted it around? even just to respond with text no image

Comment: Does it connect? if yes then how are you invoking the command? try `!hello` you can change `!` by change the `command_prefix`

Comment: The bot shows online in the server so I'm guess it is connecting? I did try !hello and !test with nothing. I was trying to work on the !say command but then that just repeated itself back into the console instead of the bot saying anything

Comment: When it connects you should get `Connected NAMEHERE` in the console. Make sure to give the bot perms